# Using strtotime to parse a date in the format d/m/Y

Tags: php, date

This is my PHP code:

```
$g = "19/06/2013"; 
echo $g." // ".date("Y/m/d", strtotime($g))
```

The output is this `19/06/2013 // 1970/01/01` instead of `19/06/2013 // 2013/06/19`.Why?

Comment: `strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$g))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `/` with `-` to convert it into a format appropriate for `strtotime` function

Use this:-

```
$g = "19/06/2013"; 
echo $g."// ". date("Y/m/d", strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$g)))
```

Comment: Or simply use DateTime class that let's you specify an arbitrary format. -1 because of trying to invent the wheel when functionality for this use case already exists and it's *not* trying to coerce the data so strtotime *might* return proper result.

Answer (score 7):

That's the "WHY?":

> Note:
>   Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

See here!: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 2):

Because `strtotime` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)) only understands [specific date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) and `d/m/Y` is not one of them.

You can make the code work by using one of the understood formats such as `d-m-Y` or `d.m.Y` (a simple `str_replace` on the input will do it), but it would be better to use the `DateTime` class for this and make everything explicit:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $g);
echo $g." // ".$dt->format('Y/m/d');
```